# Regression Analysis

Tags: regression, self-study, linear-model

Can someone help me with this problem? I am using R, so what functions I should use?

[image]

Comment: Please see [the self-study tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). P.S. `lm` ^_^

Comment: Hi Yuto, welcome to CrossValidated. Routine bookwork questions can be posted, but they are treated differently. See the link in Nick's comment above - please read it carefully - and then modify your question as appropriate (that is, we're not going to tell you directly how to do this - if you explain what you've tried and where your specific difficulties lie we will be able to give you some hints and suggestions. As Nick says, you fit regression with `lm`, but if you didn't know even that, CV will not be a suitable place for you to learn about basic use of R.

Answer (score 1):

Ater doing some self study I got this answer. I appreciate your feedback.

```r
>  # data frame for table in the picture above
>rt  <- data.frame(read.table("heightweight.txt"))  
>rt2 <- rt[-3,]
>rt3 <- lm(rt2)
>plot(rt2$V2, rt2$V1) 
>abline(lm(rt2))
>y = 143.413 + x*0.438  # where is y=175
>answer <- 72.11
```

Comment: (i) You don't need to remove the third row - the NA will cause the fit to ignore it. (ii) You can then extract the fitted value for the missing observation from the fit of the linear model, whether direct from the object or via the `fitted` function. (iii) It's best to specify the model in your call to `lm` or you're relying on the columns being in the right order.